# How to retrieve Instance user_data from aws sdk java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

The [Instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/Instance.html) class for AWS Java SDK method doesn't have user data

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.924</version>
  </dependency>
```

Which will be the right API to query AWS Instace-id User Data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user data is obtained using AWS API [DescribeInstanceAttribute](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeInstanceAttribute.html). The corresponding SDK call in Java is [describeInstanceAttribute](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2.html#describeInstanceAttribute-com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.DescribeInstanceAttributeRequest-), which is not part of the `Instance` class, but is part of [AmazonEC2Client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2Client.html) class.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin this helps which API will contain the name of the Instance ??

Comment: @anish `Instance` class has `getInstanceId` method.

Comment: Not the Insance-id the name of the Instance Itself

Comment: @anish Name is just a tag called `Name`. So use `getTags` and find this tag.

Comment: Got it It's a Dictionary Thanks it helped a lot